# How can we create a friendly environment on Islam.SE and deal with sectarianism?

Tags: discussion, moderation, quality-control, chat

In my past couple of chats, my comments are constantly been deleted by one of the moderator. If I express my opinion which that is slightly against moderation (not a moderator) my comments are deleted right away. This is extremely rude I think. Yesterday this is what I typed which was deleted soon. Basically a user and a mod was constantly chatting/arguing about why this question is not clear and why it is on hold (I see it numerous time when I enter chat), I said

> I hope I am not offending anyone here. I think the mods here have
>   plenty of time to discuss things in chat but they avoid answering
>   question on meta because of fear of not being up voted (I guess).
>   Really by wasting time on discussing these things over and over in
>   chat, one can just address it on meta and problem solved.

This comment was deleted. After this I simply asked if my comment was offending to anyone and that's why it was deleted. Another moderator replied, No (at least that is what I got). Then I wanted to sort of discuss why criticism is not tolerated here at all. Those comment were deleted right away as well and I was banned for more than one hour.

Personally I am not really against any moderator at all. I may be against some moderation decisions and am worried about sectarianism. But that is it, I have not really discussed it that much that (I think) I am troubling person. I have recently got involved again and seen these treatment after a long time. I am afraid I have been polite but nothing seems to work.

My question is:

- Is it even possible to create a friendly environment here?
- What effort can I make to address the issues that I am worried about (mainly sectarianism and quality control) while at the same time not being blocked?

Comment: The question had nothing to do with sectarianism therefore I removed it.

Comment: No this question has to do with **sectarianism**. The reason I participate in chat rooms is to address sectarianism which I think is the root cause of the problem. Basically there is *no one standard* here for all users. Now it could be just me that think that way but my question is, How I want to discuss it in chat when my comments are removed and are not allowed to participate. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** When I say *you*, I mean everyone who reads this, not particularly the OP

Best way to create a friendly environment, in my opinion, is to actually make friends. Making friends increases mutual understanding and decreases communication costs. The more you get to know people, the better you understand where they are coming from and how they perceieve events.

Best way to make friends in here is to hang out in our main chat room. Please don't visit the chat room only when you have something to complain, but come, and help us organize the tags, tell us your favorite ayahs and hadiths, complain about your noisy neighbors etc.

Exercise your [husn zann](http://alhaadi.org.za/faqihul-ummah/malfuzat/126-malfuzat-sulook/978--there-is-no-need-for-any-proof-in-order-to-have-husn-e-zann-good-thoughts-for-others.html). When you seem to have problems with someone, assume the best about them.

Everyone might have problems with moderation. Questions/answers might get deleted. This is how the world works. When this happens, don't assume the worst. Try to figure out what kind of problems your post might have. Think of it a problem solving exercise for you. If you have posted a question, is it too broad? or too open ended? or is it merely opinion based? And if you can't make your answer fit into a format that can be addressed in a Q/A style, maybe islam.SE is not a good platform to ask that question. And if your answer gets deleted first thing to check is plagirasim. StackExchange in general is very strict about it and so we are. Moreover, be sure that your answer is something more than a block-quote and link to a foreign site. If you can only answer by a block-quote, leave it to someone else to answer it. Moreover, be sure that your answer actually addresses the questions asked. If your answer is deleted and you think you can fix the problems, just post a new answer. In general, deleted answer needs fundamental changes in order to fix and those changes invalidates the current votes. Moreover, delete/edit/flag cycle is somewhat inefficent and creates more work for the mods.

And if after giving it a considerable amount of effort and you couldn't figure out what is wrong with it, bring it to meta (instead of chat). But, be careful how to present your problem. Even the title you choose to use affects how your question is perceived. **Why my question is deleted** is generally wrong aprroach here. Try **How can I improve my question/answer**. It demonstrates that you are not merely complaining but actually willing to work with the community. Moreover, if you ask why your question is deleted, only the mod who deleted it can actually answer your question. In the second format, everybody can contribute. When community helps you and your answer is improved, post it as a new answer. That way, you don't need much moderator attention. Which is better, beucase, trying to explain why some post is deleted all the time is tiresome.

And this is pretty much all I wanted to say  about the issue.

Comment: while your answer address the question for those users who's question/answers are deleted (because of low quality/plagiarism etc), I don't exactly fall in that category (did not have this problem much). I stressed my comments are constantly deleted in chatroom, and I get banned for *not so inappropriate comments*. You did not address that part which I would like to please address. Looks like there is some kind of stigma against certain users here. Are my comments that offensive to be deleted?

Comment: @muslim1 In that case, how is this different from [your other discussion](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/how-to-deal-with-a-rude-and-aggressive-moderator)?

Comment: That answer pretty much squarely put all the blame on me (even ignored moderator language). Anyways I learned form it. *Then* I posted something benign in the chat and it was quickly removed by the same moderator. I guess my point is, was my comment that offensive to be removed? Isn't there a point that other moderators may not find my comment that offensive but one moderator in particular does (and he is right). Why are we thinking that moderator cannot be at fault? All answers are pretty much single sided.